# C# - Create own Encoding for Roman8 charset

Tags: c#, encoding, decoding

The Roman8 charset is not supported by C#, but I need to use it properly (Encoding / Decoding strings), so I want to know what is the best method to create my own Encoding in order to support this Encoding?

Is that enough :

```
class Roman8Encoding : Encoding
```

What about Encoder ? Decoder ? EncoderFallback ? DecoderFallback ?

Any explanation on how do the job correctly is welcome.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have time to give details at the moment, but I created an [Encoding implementation for EBCDIC](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/ebcdic/). You could use that source code as a starting point. I wrote it a *long* time ago, so I would probably do various things differently these days - but it's a start...

Comment: I've the time, I'll wait you have the time to explain me a little be more. However, I've take a look to your solution and it's pretty similar that what I want to do :)

Comment: @Arnaud: In that case I doubt I'd have any more significant things to say. Is Roman8 as "single byte per character, always" encoding? If so, that'll make life a lot simpler. (It sounds like it, given http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_roman8)

Comment: Yes it is a single byte per character encoding ;), in what it is simpler? just need to do an translating table ?

Comment: @Arnaud: It makes the Encoder and Decoder types easier to write (if you actually need to write them yourself at all; I can't remember offhand). Yes, you basically need a translation table: byte to char and vice versa.

Comment: I'll do it like so, thanks ! Question, how can I initialize a EncoderReplacementFallback ? When a character isn't supported, I would like to print a ? at place.