# C# Encoding new Romanian characters ă ș ț

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I am trying to encode the new Romanian characters "ă ș ț" to export from DB to a CSV file. These new characters are added somewhere in 2000/01, but there are no encoding available in framework (even in .net 4.5).

One of the Romanian site explains the usage of chacters [here](http://www.secarica.ro/html/s-uri_si_t-uri.html). I have referred details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding.aspx) but that does not have any reference to iso-8859-16 encoding. If I use above encoding then C# throws exception "'ISO_8859-16' is not a supported encoding name."

Does anyone ever used this encoding before?

Sanjay

Comment: These are not new characters. I think exporting the CSV in unicode will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net does not have built-in support for ISO 8859-16. The easiest solution would be to switch to a Unicode encoding, such as UTF-8.

If you still want ISO 8859-16, you could implement it yourself. The [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding) class is extensible. As a reference, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff536023)

See this answer for an example for EBCDIC: [Create own Encoding for Roman8 charset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536825/22364)

You would need to implement the abstract methods:

```
int GetByteCount(char[], int, int)
int GetBytes(char[], int, int, byte[], int)
int GetCharCount(byte[], int, int)
int GetChars(byte[], int, int, char[], int)
int GetMaxByteCount(int)
int GetMaxCharCount(int)
```

and maybe the virtual members:

```
bool IsSingleByte { get; }
string EncodingName { get; }
```